# Python PIL Алиса

Tags: python, pil, pythonanywhere

Пользователь вводит ссылку на картинку. Программа должна наложить эффект "стереопара". Есть функция, работавшая с локальными файлами:

```
from PIL import Image


def makeanagliph(filename, delta):
im = Image.open(filename)
pixels = im.load()
x, y = im.size
im_n = Image.new('RGB', (x, y))
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
        if i < delta:
            r = 0
        else:
            r = pixels[i - delta, j][0]
        im_n.putpixel((i, j), (r, g, b))
im_n.save('res.jpg')
return None
makeanagliph("картинка.jpg", 10)
```

Нужно, чтобы вместо локальной картинки бралась ссылка на картинку из интернете, например [вот](https://pp.userapi.com/c846523/v846523364/1efadc/foCDUSkZkQI.jpg) (https://pp.userapi.com/c846523/v846523364/1efadc/foCDUSkZkQI.jpg) и с этой картинкой, без сохранений(работаем на pythonanywhere), мы должны сделать те же действия.

Кроме того, это всё должно работать быстро(ограничение 1,5 секунды)

Comment: Скачиваем картинку любым способом в объект BytesIO и этот BytesIO пихаем в Image.open, сохраняем результат тоже в BytesIO вместо файла, всё остальное как обычно

Answer (score 1):

Как и говорил @andreymal скачиваем изображение ввиде байтовой строки и открываем. А дальше все тоже самое, добавил только альфа канал.

```
import io

import requests
from PIL import Image


def makeanagliph_url(url, delta):
    image_data = requests.get(url).content
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
    pixels = im.load()
    x, y = im.size
    im_n = Image.new(im.mode, (x, y))
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            channels = list(pixels[i, j])
            if i < delta:
                channels[0] = 0
            else:
                channels[0] = pixels[i - delta, j][0]
            im_n.putpixel((i, j), tuple(channels))
    im_n.save('res.{}'.format('png' if len(channels) == 4 else 'jpg'))
    print('Image saved')

    # сохранение в байтовой строке
    byteArray = io.BytesIO()
    im_n.save(byteArray, format='png' if len(channels) == 4 else 'jpeg')
    print(byteArray.getvalue())



url1 = 'https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png'
url2 = 'http://romillyhills.co.uk/images/python%20logo.jpg'

from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
makeanagliph_url(url1, 10)
print(datetime.now() - start_time)

start_time = datetime.now()
makeanagliph_url(url2, 10)
print(datetime.now() - start_time)
```

Результат

```
Image saved
0:00:00.455363
Image saved
0:00:00.670091
```

[image: Python_logo.png]  [image: Python_logo.jpg]

Comment: Ээээ... `im_n.save('res.{}'.format('png' if len(channels) == 4 else 'jpg')`. Нужно ведь тоже в BytesIO сохранять (автор в вопросе уточнял, что нельзя в файлы сохранять). В save передавайте вместо строки имени файла объект BytesIO, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6ddfad4f8b84ed62390a608fd941756e5647ef69/pil_pillow__examples/image_to_bytes/main.py#L13